# What is the difference between a line integral and Riemann-Stieltjes integral?

Tags: integration, riemann-integration, stieltjes-integral

I'm particularly concerned with the visual representation of line integration. The following is provided by Wikipedia [image]

while this is shown in the Wikihow page

[image]

Lastly, the Riemann-Stieltjes integral
[image]

They seem to be constructed in very different ways... is there some unified view that makes them all agree with one another?

Comment: There are different line integrals. What you grabbed from Wikipedia is the one of a scalar field that has the infinitesimal arc length $|r'(t)|\,dt$ in it.  I claim that the line integral of a [vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Line_integral_of_a_vector_field) is a sum of Stieltjes-integrals. Pretty straighforward when you consider that the RS integral $\int_0^t f(s)\,dg(s)$ is $\int_0^tf(s)\,g'(s)\,ds$ when the integrating function is differentiable. There is no disturbing modulus applied to $g'(s)$. That's why it works.

Comment: Even the line integral of a [scalar field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Line_integral_of_a_scalar_field) $\int_a^bf(r(t))|r'(t)|\,dt$ can be turned into a Stieltjes integral: Set $s(t)=\int_0^t|r'(v)|\,dv$ (arc length) and write the line integral as $\int_a^bf(r(t))\,ds(t)=\int_a^bf(r(t))\,s'(t)\,dt\,.$

Comment: @KurtG.  Is line integral over scalar field are related to measure theory? that is they are integral with respect to some measure on some measure space?

Comment: @MeetPatel Every integral is related to measure theory. The relevant measure space here is an interval on the real line and Lebesgue measure. The Stieltjes integral is a special case of this. Do we now have to rewrite all books about line integrals? Probably not because when we apply line integrals the integrated functions are usually Riemann integrable.